# Are there any specific problems connected with context switch?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency

Bob Martin's [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) book contains the following rule on concurrent programming:

> **Run with More Threads Than Processors.** Things happen when the system
>   switches between tasks. To encourage task swapping, run with more
>   threads than processors or cores. The more frequently your tasks swap,
>   the more likely you’ll encounter code that is missing a critical
>   section or causes deadlock.

I had been considering such nice things of concurrency as deadlocks, race conditions, etc. to be a characteristic of concurrency per se whether our threads are governed by a single core (with switching) or by multiple ones.

So what is the rationale of the rule? Is it just some kind of heuristic? What are the specific problems associated with context switching? (I am aware that context switch causes a burden of overheads but is not that advice on it, is it? ).

Comment: More context switches just means more chances of something "bad" happening if there's problems in the code. Lets say your program have a bug which only occurs once every thousand context switch. If you run just two threads it will take longer to reach the limit, but if you run 20 threads you speed it up by a factor of ten.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude My question was about what is that 'something bad' that is specific to namely context switch. If my code has a subtle bug (for ex. some deadlock) then it will come to the surface whether the app is running under the number of threads that is more than the amount of cores or not, will not? But if I understood you correctly the advice is just on increasing of possibility of appering bugs typical to concurrency.

Comment: No there's nothing bad that could happen by the context switch alone (or the whole OS would be very buggy!) but more context switches and more threads increase the chance of making bugs in your code to appear. Another example: Deadlocks could happen with only two threads, but sometimes such bugs could happen very seldom with only two or three threads, but the chances of it occurring increases with the number of threads that attempt to access the shared resource.